# How LinkedIn is able to import gmail contacts without asking for password

Tags: api, gmail, linkedin-api, google-oauth

How LinkedIn is able to import gmail contacts without asking for password.

> **check this link:**
>
> https://www.linkedin.com/fetch/importAndInviteEntry

How can I create same feature for my site???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Linkedin is using 3 legged OAuth and the Google Contact APIs to pull information from your Google Apps account.

COntact API documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/
OAuth 2.0 3LO: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

This should get you started

Comment: I gone through the document but.. without password I still can not figure out how can import gmail contacts if user is logged in to gmail.

Comment: which password are you referring to?